# An html button that runs the python script that created the html page in the first place

Tags: python, html

I'm experimenting with creating a web-based platform for assessing students in basic maths. My background is in maths, not computing, so I'm a bit new to all this, but please bear with me.

I spent some time last year writing python scripts which create questions with some random parameters and calculate their solutions, then print .pdf files of questions and master .pdfs with all the solutions. Now we want to put the questions and answers on the web.

In more detail, I've written a python script that creates an .html file, and opens it. The script contains the same calculations as before, so it chooses some appropriate parameters and works out the answer. The page then contains a question with some random parameters thrown in, and a button to reveal the answer. When the student presses the button, it reveals another button, which if pressed is supposed to reload the page with different parameters chosen - so, I want this button to run the python script which creates the .html file.

That's the bit I don't know how to do. I've seen some examples on here of getting a button to run a python script, but not the one the made the html file in the first place. Is there a way to do this? Or is it a bad idea altogether?

I'm using ubuntu and python 2.7 by the way, but ultimately whatever I make will have to work in windows too.

Any help appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have this working on the web, this would work

```
<form method="GET" action="/same/url/as/this/page">
  <input type="submit" value="Press Me!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ultimate goal is to make a web platform for taking math exams some thing like [this](http://www.singpath.com) making this in core python will be more hectic and time consuming you'll have to write everything which has to be handled by the web-application the url-routing, page templating, the question generator(which you have already written) and many other things.

Instead of which what you can do is take a web-framework(e.g. [django](https://www.djangoproject.com), [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org), etc ) and work with it which will make your process much simpler and easier. I prefer you should use django which has a good community of developers if you stuck somewhere and has many online tutorials which I'll list below also you don't have to develop the admin site from scratch. In short what you're trying to achieve can be easily done using a web-framework.

### Why should one use web-framework ?

A framework wraps basic functionalities needed in a easy to implement way. And prevents Re-Inventing the wheel

Why should you use a framework?

1. Modularity - Simple MVC architecture, helps to make more maintainable, scalable and readable. Since, most of the developers are familiar with MVC it even makes it easy for them to understand.
2. Built In features - Some frameworks have the built in features which are heavily used by developers. For Java Play framework supports hot reload. Just make a change in java and it will compile and run it in your browser. For web frameworks like Angular, think easy routing and controller assignment. It would take months to make something on similar lines using vanilla JS
3. Common Libs :- Frameworks do provide the most common things devs use in an easy fashion. Angular JS has $http service to make backend calls. Many other built in services reduce the burden of re inventing the wheel.
4. Other Framework support : Some frameworks are also collaborated with other frameworks easily. Bootstrap a CSS framework can be easily integrated with Angular JS. using bootstrap ui

### Some Tutorial which will guide you through Django:

1. Coding For Entrepreneur - [trydjango](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdPf-pNK1s0&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzQSEMN5PXvEWuD2gEWVngCZ)
2. Django girls [Tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/)
3. [Learn Django](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNQxxpM1yOs&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeA05ZouE4OzDYLHY-XH-Nd)

I hope it helps :)